# How to edit my VBA macro to fix the Run-time error '1004' regarding my Pivot Table creation?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

my below macro works fine up until the final block of code beginning at:
"Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _:
What I need to accomplish is simply to account for a varying range from the "Details" sheet and to insert all of that data onto the "Summary" sheet for a PivotTable. When running the below code, the error I receive is "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". After going through the forum, I thought that maybe it is because I was referencing the incorrect sheet but that doesn't seem to be the underlying issue.

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim Details As Worksheet
    Dim Summary As Worksheet
    Dim numberOfLoans As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim Client As Variant
    
    Sub dob_cfa()
    
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Details"
    Set Details = Worksheets("Details")
    Columns(7).Insert
    Columns(11).Insert
    Range("G1").Value = "SEC MORTGAGOR DOB BLANKS"
    Range("K1").Value = "SEC CO MORTGAGOR DOB BLANKS"
    Range("M1").Value = "CLIENT NAME"
    
    Client = InputBox("What is the client name + event?")
    Range("M2").Value = Client
    Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(0,11) = Client
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("M2").Copy
    Range("M3:M" & LastRow).Select
    Details.Paste
    Columns("A:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    Cells(1,1).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    numberOfLoans = ActiveCell.row - 1
    
    For row = 1 To numberOfLoans
    
    If Cells(row + 1, 4) <> ""And Cells(row + 1, 6) = "" Then
     Cells(row + 1, 7) = "BLANK"
    End If
    
    Next row
    
    Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets("Details")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
    Set Summary = Worksheets("Summary")
    
    LastRow = Details.Cells(Rows.Count, 1). End(xlUp).row
    LastCol = Details.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = Details.Cells(1,1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Summary.Cells(2,1), _
    TableName:="DOBPivot")
```

Comment: Remove the `. _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Summary.Cells(2,1), _
    TableName:="DOBPivot")`.

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks @BigBen